Postgres NULL on composite types
To get to the point - i understand why these are true
select (null, null) is null;
select null is null as null_is_null;

I also understand why these are all false, resp. return null
select (null, null) is not null as null_null_is_not_null;
select null is not null as null_is_not_null;
select (null, null) = (null, null) as null_null_eq_null_null;
select (null, null) = null as null_null_eq_null_null;
select (null, null) != (null, null) as null_null_neq_null_null;
select (null, null) != null as null_null_neq_null_null;

But there are two aspects that puzzle me:

All this implies that as a user, I have no way to distinguish between null and (null, null) - which in my representation may have different meanings.
If all of the above is valid...then explain this to me:

select coalesce((null, null), (10, 20)) as magic;

returns
 magic 
-------
 (,)
(1 row)

One would expect that as per documentation

The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null.

But we just established that (null, null) is null.
(Full script here)

This is all a mess. Read this thread from the pgsql-hackers list. In a nutshell, PostgreSQL says that (NULL, NULL) IS NULL because the SQL standard says it must, but it treats the composite as different from NULL in all other respects. We never found a consistent solution, and we don't think there is a way to interpret the SQL standard in a consistent fashion.

I get it now, thanks for the reference. I can utilize the is distinct from operator. However, it may be viable to update the documentation to say that coalesce  returns the first of its arguments that is distinct from null.

I agree with that.
